# boost library not found

Tags: c++, windows, boost

```
  boost_system
          boost_filesystem
          boost_thread
          boost_date_time
          boost_chrono
          boost_regex
          boost_serialization
          boost_program_options

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:112 (find_package)
```

Trying to build a windows application and getting above error when using boost..i need help in creating the build but running into this error...
I have installed visual studio 2017 and cmake 3.8.2 with boost version 1_64_0.

after many try i used this link to https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=11187
 replace my findboost.make file with http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-May/014131.html

now the build completes but there is no .exe file created.

please help me understand the build process and missing steps or configuration to complete the build

Comment: And what is your *specific* question?

Comment: i solved this by installing the boost library and compelling them to generate the output as per your system configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> Download boost and unzip and configure
>
> 3.1 Rub bootstrap.ksh
>
> 3.2 run b2.exe address-model=32,64 --build-type=complete (takes approx 2 hours)
>
> 3.3 Stage folder will be updated in same folder
>
> 3.2 set below variables

```
    BOOST_INCLUDEDIR D:\Softwares\boost_1_64_0      
    BOOST_LIBRARYDIR D:\Softwares\boost_1_64_0\stage\lib
    Boost_LIBRARIES D:\Softwares\boost_1_64_0\stage\lib
```